# Where to start in building an app/system that compresses and decompresses a file

Tags: java, android, algorithm, compression

I'm currently developing an application in Java/Android that allows the user to compress and decompress files. At first, I started to study the file size such as:

```
1Byte = 8Bits
1KB = 1024Byte
1MB = 1024KB
1GB = 1024MB
1TB = 1024GB
1PB = 1024TB
1EB = 1024PB
1ZB = 1024EB
1YB = 1024ZB
```

After I studied this, I studied and read some articles on the net and found out there are 2 types of file compression (Correct me if I'm wrong): Lossless and Lossy. Lossless compression means that a file is compressed into a smaller bit without losing any single file while lossy compression means that important files were being removed while compressing the file.

I also read that compression(run-length coding method) is like this:

```
AAABBCCDFFFFEEEEH
```

to this:

```
3A2B2CD4F4EH
```

which gives me an idea on how compressing/decompressing works on file.

I also searched the net that there is an API for compressing file on java(also applicable on android) which is

```
java.util.zip
```

I also tried some codes on compressing and decompressing file from various helpful websites/forum/etc (including stackoverflow.com) which gives me an experience to this study.

I also read about algorithms used in data compression which are

```
 Huffman encoding algorithm -  assigns a code to characters in a file based on how frequently those characters occur

run-length encoding - generates a two-part value for repeated characters: the first part specifies the number of times the character is repeated, and the second part identifies the character

Lempel-Ziv algorithm - converts variable-length strings into fixed-length codes that consume less space than the original strings.
```

Now, I need to know how to code an algo in compressing and decompressing file by using java.util.zip(I also don't know how to use it. tutorials on net is not working for me :/). What algo does winzip, winrar, compressed folder(windows), and androzip(android app) is using? Will someone please teach me step by step(treat me as an unschooled person) on how java.util.zip works and the different algorithms. sorry for the long post folks. Thanks for the future help and posts(if there will be)!

Comment: Your question might be too broad to be answered here. In any case, for use of java.util.zip, see http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-compress-files-in-zip-format/

Comment: If you can't follow a tutorial, what makes you think one written here will be easier to follow? You need to specify what it is you're having difficulty with, or nobody will be able to help you.

Comment: cklab, thanks for your suggestion! I'll include this in my study list.

Comment: Nick, I thought of someone who can send me a site where I can easily understand the tutorial and every instruction is explained in details or maybe a mentor over the net? thanks for the advice though :)

Answer (score 0):

```
public static final byte[] unzip(byte[] in) throws IOException {
// decompress using GZIPInputStream 
ByteArrayOutputStream outStream = 
  new ByteArrayOutputStream(EXPECTED_COMPRESSION_RATIO * in.length);

GZIPInputStream inStream = 
  new GZIPInputStream ( new ByteArrayInputStream(in) );

byte[] buf = new byte[BUF_SIZE];
while (true) {
  int size = inStream.read(buf);
  if (size <= 0) 
    break;
  outStream.write(buf, 0, size);
}
outStream.close();

return outStream.toByteArray();
}


public static final byte[] zip(byte[] in) {
try {
  // compress using GZIPOutputStream 
  ByteArrayOutputStream byteOut= 
    new ByteArrayOutputStream(in.length / EXPECTED_COMPRESSION_RATIO);

  GZIPOutputStream outStream= new GZIPOutputStream(byteOut);

  try {
    outStream.write(in);
  } catch (Exception e) {
    LOG.error("", e);
  }

  try {
    outStream.close();
  } catch (IOException e) {
      LOG.error("", e);
  }

  return byteOut.toByteArray();

} catch (IOException e) {
    LOG.error("", e);
  return null;
}
}
```

Comment: Well if this helps? That guy want a step by step solution.

Comment: Thanks for the post! Maybe I can use this for future reference. Also thanks for understanding my problem rekire :)